# How to catch Exceptions correctly in PHP and MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, exception, try-catch

My question is about the correct way to catch exceptions in PHP.
Based on the accompanying [examples](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-driver/crud/) of the PHP MongoDB driver, I 
have created the following script:

```
<?php

try {

    $mng = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:2717");
    $query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query([], ['sort' => [ 'name' => 1], 'limit' => 5]);     

    $rows = $mng->executeQuery("testdb.cars", $query);

    foreach ($rows as $row) {

        echo "$row->name : $row->price\n";
    }

} catch (MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception $e) {

    $filename = basename(__FILE__);

    echo "The $filename script has experienced an error.\n"; 
    echo "It failed with the following exception:\n";

    echo "Exception:", $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    echo "In file:", $e->getFile(), "\n";
    echo "On line:", $e->getLine(), "\n";       
}

?>
```

The example is educational and meant to be run on the PHP CLI. In PHP CLI, we get all the exceptions on the console, but for didactic purposes, I wanted to catch exceptions in the try/catch block.

I have seen more Java code than PHP and therefore, catching a generic `MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception` does not look good to me. In Java, we catch specific exceptions and have multiple try/catch blocks for different kinds of exceptions.

The driver has the following Exceptions:

```
MongoDB\Driver\Exception\AuthenticationException
MongoDB\Driver\Exception\BulkWriteException 
MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionException 
MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException 
MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception 
MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ExecutionTimeoutException 
MongoDB\Driver\Exception\InvalidArgumentException 
MongoDB\Driver\Exception\LogicException 
MongoDB\Driver\Exception\RuntimeException 
MongoDB\Driver\Exception\SSLConnectionException 
MongoDB\Driver\Exception\UnexpectedValueException 
MongoDB\Driver\Exception\WriteException
```

Is this a kosher way to catch exceptions in PHP?

Answer (score 5):

How about placing a switch statement in the catch part, and determine the exception's type with the [`instanceof`](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.instanceof.php) language construct or the [`get_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) function?

For example:

```
[...]

} catch(\Exception $e) {
   switch (get_class($e)) {
     case 'MongoDB\Driver\Exception\AuthenticationException':
       // do stuff
       break;

     case 'MongoDB\Driver\Exception\BulkWriteException':
     //etc, etc...
   }
}
```

At first, I would examine the return values of get_class(), to make sure you I'm comparing the result with the exact exception names.

Comment: We could do it in such a way, but is this the recommended way to catch exceptions in PHP? If so, why?

Answer (score 4):

You can add multiple catch statements

```
<?php

try {

    $mng = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:2717");
    $query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query([], ['sort' => [ 'name' => 1], 'limit' => 5]);     

    $rows = $mng->executeQuery("testdb.cars", $query);

    foreach ($rows as $row) {

        echo "$row->name : $row->price\n";
    }

} catch (MongoDB\Driver\Exception\AuthenticationException $e) {

    echo "Exception:", $e->getMessage(), "\n";
} catch (MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionException $e) {

    echo "Exception:", $e->getMessage(), "\n";
} catch (MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException $e) {

    echo "Exception:", $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: This is how it is done in Java. The question is if it is the proper way to go. 
(I did not see code in PHP that way.) And the `MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception` also catches the `ConnectionTimeoutException ` so maybe it is redundat to do it this way.

Comment: Yes, It is the Java way and same in the PHP. For more information you can see http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php. MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception is the generic class to catch all the exceptions and must be used as a fallback for exceptions not specifically caught in catch statements.

Answer (score 1):

Adding multiple catch statement I think it's a better approach than switch. However, what if the exception isn't from these classes with a switch you should have a default case and also if you do it with multiple catches.

```
try {

$mng = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:2717");
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query([], ['sort' => [ 'name' => 1], 'limit' => 5]);     

$rows = $mng->executeQuery("testdb.cars", $query);

foreach ($rows as $row) {

    echo "$row->name : $row->price\n";
}

} catch (MongoDB\Driver\Exception\AuthenticationException $e) {
    echo "AuthenticationException:", $e->getMessage(), "\n";

} catch (MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionException $e) {
    echo "ConnectionException:", $e->getMessage(), "\n";

} catch (MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException $e) {
    echo "ConnectionTimeoutException:", $e->getMessage(), "\n";

}catch (\Exception $e) {
       echo "Exception:", $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```